# Pandas: replace certain values within groups using group maximus

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my table:

| category | number | probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1102 | 24 | 0.3 |
| 1102 | 18 | 0.6 |
| 1102 | 16 | 0.1 |
| 2884 | 24 | 0.16 |
| 2884 | 15 | 0.8 |
| 2884 | 10 | 0.04 |

so I want to replace the number column that has probability lower than 15% with the number that has the highest probability within groups:

| category | number | probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1102 | 24 | 0.3 |
| 1102 | 18 | 0.6 |
| 1102 | **18** | 0.1 |
| 2884 | 24 | 0.16 |
| 2884 | 15 | 0.8 |
| 2884 | **15** | 0.04 |

Comment: should 1002 be 1102 in category?

Comment: yes I am sorry will correct it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the number corresponding to max prob in a group then use loc to update values

```
n = df.sort_values('probability').groupby('category')['number'].transform('last')
df.loc[df['probability'] <= 0.15, 'number'] = n
```

---

```
   category  number  probability
0      1102      24         0.30
1      1102      18         0.60
2      1102      18         0.10
3      2884      24         0.16
4      2884      15         0.80
5      2884      15         0.04
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `drop_duplicates` to get the number with highest probabilities, then replace with `np.where`:

```
highest_prob = df.sort_values('probability').drop_duplicates('category', keep='last').set_index('category')['number')

df['number'] = np.where(df['probability'] < 0.15, df['category'].map(highest_prob), df['number'])
```

Comment: this works but sort_values need to use "probability" rather than "number"

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
ser = df.groupby("category")["number"].transform("idxmax")
​
df["number"] = np.where(df["probability"].lt(0.15), ser , df["number"])
​
```

Output :

```
print(df)
   category  number  probability
0      1102      24         0.30
1      1102      18         0.60
2      1002       2         0.10
3      2884      24         0.16
4      2884      15         0.80
5      2884       3         0.04
```